# Help with usbasp pinout

Tags: usbasp

I am having trouble figuring out the pinout of my 6 - pin USBasp Chinese clone that I got off eBay.
**BEFORE YOU TELL ME TO LOOK AT THE PINOUT DIAGRAMS,** I can tell you that my version of the usbasp has no way of telling which way is up and which ways is down. Images:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you look at the triangle on the side of the connector?

Comment: The pin labeled “Or this pin?” is pin number 1: look at the key on the left side of the connector.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the following pinout diagram (from [telecnatron.com](http://telecnatron.com/reference/pinouts/avr-isp/index.html)):

[image]

The right-hand diagram above shows the USBASP-board pin-header pin assignments, when you are looking into the pin-header.  The header shell will have a triangle marking pin 1.  Note that pin 1 is on the same side of the connector as the key (the ridge on the cable connectors, the slot on the pin-header shell).  Each socket on the cable also will have a triangle marking pin 1.